# Not sure what's producing this input bug in my ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a personal project with ReactJS. Currently I'm trying to emulate a multi step login component similar to the one Google has. My issue is that when I type data into the email input and click next, the data gets copied to the password input that is conditionally rendered. Here are some images for clarity: 
[when I type anything into this field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QC3WL.jpg) and click next,
[the password input gets filled with the email input's data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1nSo.jpg).

Here is my component code, imports have been omitted:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      emailIsValid: false,
      passwordIsValid: false
    };
  }
```

These methods to keep track of the login steps, bear in mind that these are incomplete and will make http requests to an API for validation:

```
  verifyEmail = () => {
    this.setState({
      emailIsValid: !this.state.emailIsValid
    });
  };

 loginUser = () => {};
```

And here's the render method, I made conditional statements to show/hide the email and password inputs:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="login-container">
        <div className="login-panel">
          <div className="logo">Matshop</div>
          <form>
            {!this.state.emailIsValid ? (
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="brucewayne@gmail.com"
                />
                <a href="/"> Forgot your email?</a>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" />
                <a href="/"> Forgot your password?</a>
              </div>
            )}
          </form>

          <div className="login-footer">
            {!this.state.emailIsValid ? (
              <div className="login-buttons">
                <button onClick={this.verifyEmail}>Next</button>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className="login-buttons">
                <button className="back-btn" onClick={this.verifyEmail}>
                  Back
                </button>
                <button onClick={this.loginUser}>Login</button>
              </div>
            )}
            <p>
              Need an account?<a href="/Register"> click here</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Are you planning to bind each input value to a component state value and change/input handlers to update the respective value on each event? https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: You need individual state properties for email and password. Each input element needs event handler function call in onChange of input element and value prop to input element. This is how you should handle

Comment: add `onChange` and `value` properties to the `input` elements. Google "react controlled input"

Comment: other than the comments above, I see 2 more issues. **Firstly**, don't use `<a>` tags unless you want to send the user to an external link, otherwise it would refresh the page. **Secondly**, your form will be submitted when the user presses `enter` key. You're not handling this case and thus would probably refresh the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, they were helpful!